# Where can I put app wide config in an Angular 2 project

Tags: angular

What method can I use, in an Angular2 (using CLI and Webpack) project, to place common config data and parameters such as some api keys or API URLs? These parameters will be used by many components and services.

- In a dedicated service?
- In a yaml or json parsed through something (again a service?)?
- In a module exporting an object?

Our app is becoming pretty big and I try to find a solution to keep the app as light and efficient as possible.

Comment: It depends on the build system. I assume your API urls differ if you run the app in a local or production environment. What do you use, SystemJS, Webpack ?

Comment: We have indeed two environments: dev, prod. We use webpack as it's an Angular-CLI project. Updated the question.

Comment: I don't think there's a common way to to this. There is a webpack starter project: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter which provides a mechanism for configuring environment variables at build time.  Take a look at the METADATA object in webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js . Maybe you can _steal_ from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a full-blown service or module just to store config data.

You could put your config info in a `const` and expose the variable through dependency injection:

```ts
const SETTINGS = {
  apiUrl: 'someUrl',
  apiKey: 'someKey',
  // ...
};

// Then, in your AppModule, declare the value for DI
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'SETTINGS', useValue: SETTINGS },
    // ...
  ]
})
```

Then, whenever you need to access the config (in a service or a component...), inject it:

```ts
import { Inject } from "@angular/core";

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('SETTINGS') private settings: any) {
  }
}
```

The upside of this approach is that you can use different settings based on the environment, or whether you're running unit tests, etc.

Comment: Un grand merci ;) Thanks.